# Moving a edited video out of Photos and back in, returns video to original state, not edited state

Tags: photos, photos.app, files.app

On iPhone, I took a video in portrait mode and edited it (rotated it) to be in landscape mode.  It played in landscape mode.  I used Image Capture to copy this video to my Mac.  Two files showed up in a Finder folder:

IMG_5718.MOV <— but it was still portrait, on Mac

IMG_5718.AAE

I had deleted the video from Photos on the iPhone.  Then I Air Dropped the above two files from my Mac to my iPhone, which showed up in the Downloads folder in the Files app.  I selected the two files, Shared and Save Video.  The video showed up in Photos app, but it was playing in portrait, not landscape mode.

Why doesn't it play in the edited state, which is landscape?  Did the AAE file get copied from the Files app to Photos app?  If not, how do I copy it over?

Comment: Photos maintains the original file and the edits separately.  Since the original file is portrait, that's what plays.

Comment: @MarcWilson My understanding is that the .AAE file stores the edits.  Is it possible that this was not copied from the Files app to the Photos app?  If so, then maybe this is why the .MOV file plays in the original unedited state?  How do I copy the .AAE file over?